# Why does my python program keep looping even when it shouldnt?

Tags: python

Im trying to make a slots program and it seems that for some reason my program keeps looping even though it shouldnt. It worked fine until I added he youGot variable. Not enough words so :

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ac elementum lorem. Nunc id enim iaculis massa egestas porttitor vitae sed risus. Aliquam fermentum sem felis, vel tristique massa ultricies et. Sed mattis lectus dui, id suscipit tortor accumsan id. Phasellus mollis dapibus dolor id eleifend. Phasellus ex sapien, dictum quis iaculis eu, ornare at massa. Duis facilisis facilisis lectus, ut viverra magna mattis vitae.

```
import random

#generate numbers

spinTime = float(random.randint(7, 18))

actualSpin = 0


while(actualSpin != spinTime):
    print("""
         B 7 @
         % # +
         $ J & """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "Nothing"
    print(" \n"*100)

    print("""
         7 7 7
         # $ J
         & % & """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "7"
    print(" \n" * 100)

    print("""
         7 % 7
         B B B
         & % & """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "Bar"
    print(" \n" * 100)

    print("""
         $ # &
         % % %
         J J & """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "%"
    print(" \n" * 100)

    print("""
         7 + 7
         # $ J
         # # # """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "#"
    print(" \n" * 100)


    print("""
         7 $ %
         + + +
         B B + """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "+"
    print(" \n" * 100)


    print("""
         7 $ %
         & & &
         B % + """)

    actualSpin += 1
    youGot = "&"
    print(" \n" * 100)

print("You got a:",youGot)
```

Comment: The point of having a minimum amount of words to make a post is to ensure that you properly explain the problem you're having and what solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

Since you increment 6 times in your loop, the program will only stop if `spinTime` is a multiple of 6. Otherwise it will go on forever.

Try a `<` for your loop condition:

```
while actualSpin < spinTime:
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly don't want `spinTime` to be a `float` if you're making an equality comparison. Try keeping it as an `int`. This way, `actualSpin != spinTime` will be `True` at some point providing `spinTime` is incremented only once each time round the loop (which it isn't: see the other answer).

If you must have non-integer `spinTime`, compare with `actualSpin <= spinTime`.

Comment: This will have no impact here: even though it is a float, it will still be represented exactly since it's cast from an int.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop, the value of `actualSpin` will be `7` in the first iteration, `14` in second, `21` in third, and so on. Unless you're lucky and generated random number `spinTime` is `7` or `14`, the loop will go on forever. And since you do not seed the random number generator with something like a current time, it will generate the same number every time you run it.

I don't really understand the logic of your program or what are you trying to do, but this is the *reason* why it keeps looping.

Answer (score 0):

Both @xnx and @Jan have good tips for you.

spinTime should not be cast to a float.  Even if it won't affect this situation, it is bad form.

As @Jan points out, you need to check the value of actualSpin after every time you increment it, otherwise you have a 6-in-7 chance of missing the number.

Another option would be to change the while loop to

```
    while(actualSpin <= spinTime)
```

However, that will heavily bias toward the last selection in your while loop due to the prior problem.